# OsmDroid marker not visible

Tags: android, osmdroid

I put some marker on MapView and I try to set ZoomLevel 22, but the markers are not visible.
If I set ZoomLevel to 21, markers are visible.
How can I solve ?

Comment: which version of osmdroid are you using ??

Comment: I use OsmDroid 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Where did you search before posting this question? Obviously we (I'm one of the osmdroid maintainers) missed something in the documentation to make this issue more obvious. It's been asked many times on SO and I'll happily take the points. It's also asked several times a month on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues) and it's in the [FAQ](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/FAQ#i-zoomed-past-level-20-and-the-everything-disappeared). So, please help us improve.

On to the real answer. Bottom line is that it's a known limitation of osmdroid caused by integer overflow at zoom levels greater than 20. At 20, you're generally ok, but past 20, all map data may disappear or appear in the wrong location. The map may also fling off to the north pole to generally to a location that's unexpected.

Comment: Ok, there will be a solution in the future?

Comment: probably, it's not an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Great, is it possible to estimate when?

Comment: when will it be available to use Zoom level grater than 20 ?